# Mac/iPad MobileProvision not getting added

Tags: macos, ipad

I walked through getting they cert setup, and it created a .mobileprovision which I downloaded to my Downloads folder. I have Organizer open with my iPad connected. Under Provisioning Profiles under my iPad I drag in the .mobileprovision file but it doesn't add it in the list. I tried via the + (add) button also but no matter what I do the file doesn't get added to my iPad's provisioning Profiles.

Any ideas how I can get this added so I can test on my iPad?

Comment: Try restarting xCode.  I have had similar issues in the past and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a button on provisioning that says "Use as development". Had to click that first, then I could add provisioning files.